# Using passed argument list in a function

Tags: c++, multithreading, variadic-functions

I'm trying to build a Thread Manager system in C++, which I give commands to, and if there is a thread available, it starts working. I made a template, because i don't assume how a function should look like that gets passed to the system, and because I want it to work on functions in general.

The whole concepts is theoretical for me. My idea is:

- It gets the function
- If a thread is available, it runs it
- If it's finished, it detaches the thread

So I could keep track of how many threads are being used.

```
template <typename _Ty> void ThreadManager::Run(_Ty T, ...) //T should be a function
{
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
    while (!is_free_thread_available())std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, T);

    auto F = void[=]() {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms); //to make sure the thread will be added to the vector
        T(args); //i assume this should not work
        for (int i = 0; i < Threads.size(); i++)     //Threads = std::vector<std::thread>
            auto& t = Threads[i];
            if (std::this_thread::get_id() == t.get_id())
            {
                Threads.erase(Threads.begin() + i); t.detach(),  break; //not sure if detaching the active thread works
            }
    }

    std::thread Thread(F);
    Threads.push_back(Thread);

}
```

This code doesn't run. It returns an unresolved external symbol. I might need a little help with making it run

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: Do you have this in a separate `.cpp` file from a template class definition in a header file?

Comment: A couple of notes. (1) Identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (`_Ty`) are reserved to the implementation for any use. Better avoid them for risk of undefined behavior. (2) C variable argument functions are not the way to go here. You need a variadic template.

Comment: The shown algorithm is very inefficient, and relies on busy-waiting, which nearly always indicates a flawed approach. The described algorithm should use mutexes and condition variables.

Comment: Re, "...how a function should look like that gets passed to the system." I don't have time to give a proper answer, but instead of accepting function pointers and arguments, your "manager" could accept [function _objects_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) that all have the same, possibly empty, argument list; and then you can supply [_lambda expressions_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) that _capture_ any other values that can't be passed through the argument list.

Comment: P.S., I'm not sure, but the thing that you are calling "thread manager" might be the same as what other people call "[thread _pool_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you use C++, avoid C-ellipsis and use variadic template:

That would fix your compilation issue:

```
template <typename Func, typename ... Args>
void ThreadManager::Run(Func func, Args... args)
{
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

    while (!is_free_thread_available()) std::this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);

    auto F = void[=]() {
        func(args...);

        // TODO: Synchronization needed to avoid race condition
        for (int i = 0; i < Threads.size(); i++)     //Threads = std::vector<std::thread>
            auto& t = Threads[i];
            if (std::this_thread::get_id() == t.get_id())
            {
                Threads.erase(Threads.begin() + i);
                break;
            }
    }
    // TODO: Synchronization needed to avoid race condition
    Threads.emplace_back(F);
}
```

Notice that you have also to fix your synchronizations issues